# 'sed' replacement does not seem to work on the command line

Tags: unix

The following command:

```
echo "/tmp/ansible_gN946Q/chronograf-1.4.0.1-1/etc/blue" | sed  's/(((chronograf|influxdb|kapacitor).[0-9\.-]*\/)|telegraf\/)/aefgae/g'
```

Outputs:

```
/tmp/ansible_gN946Q/chronograf-1.4.0.1-1/etc/blue
```

When the expected output is:

```
/tmp/ansible_gN946Q/aefgaeetc/blue
```

This is strange because it replaces fine in [PCRE](https://regexr.com/3j90v), which `sed` should be compatible with, correct me if I am wrong.

Hope someone can point out my error in the `sed` command above.

Comment: Please have a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

The following works:

```
sed -E 's:(((chronograf|influxdb|kapacitor).[0-9.-]*/)|telegraf/):aefgae:g'<<<'/tmp/ansible_gN946Q/chronograf-1.4.0.1-1/etc/blue'
```

Outputs:

```
/tmp/ansible_gN946Q/aefgaeetc/blue
```

Differences between your implementation and mine:

- Using `-E` *option* with `sed`

  - Interpret regular expressions as extended (modern) regular
         expressions rather than basic regular expressions (BRE's).  The
         re_format(7) manual page fully describes both formats.
- Using `<<<` instead of `echo` and `|`
- Using `:` as a *seperator* instead of `/` in the `sed` *expression* because the *input* has `/` in it.
- Using `'` instead of `"` around *input* so no shell expansion occurs on *input*.

**Note:** You could still use `echo` and `|` however it's a needless use of `echo` when it doesn't need to be used. Otherwise, the other differences, using `-E` and `:` as a *separator* instead of `/`, because *input* has `/` in it, is really what fixes what's wrong in your implementation.